# How to show form validation message for particular field in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

Here I want to show validation message for different fields

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run('email') == FALSE)
        {
            print_r('Enter email');
        }


if ($this->form_validation->run('password') == FALSE)
        {
            print_r('Enter password ');
        }
```

if i give password and leave email field empty, both messages are showing in rest api

Can anyone help me

Comment: Try adding `return;` statement after each validation message.

Comment: If I add return; after each message it shows 'Enter email' message if leave password field empty,
still not working

Comment: try `===` in place of `==`

Comment: still not working @PraveenKumar it shows "enter valid email" if i give invalid password

Comment: @G.AshokKumar Please check my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case i think this will work just fine

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
$this->form_validation->run();
if (form_error('email'))
{
    echo 'Enter email';
    exit;
}
if (form_error('password'))
{
    echo 'Enter password';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Welcome and glad it helped you... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
             $errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
             echo json_encode($errors);
        }
```

The above code also works fine, it also shows the correct error messages in rest server codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Base on point your ask

> if i give password and leave email field empty, both messages are
>   showing in rest api

Just adding attribute required in your input.

```html
<form action="https://stackoverflow.com/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">


      <p>
          <input class="email_input" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="yourmail@gmail.com" required>
      </p>
      

      <p>
          <input class="password_input" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Your password" required>
      </p>

      <p>
           <input class="enter-button" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="ENTER">
      </p>

      </form>
```

Comment: I am using codeigniter rest server, so there is no html page, I am doing this with only controller and model